# Si acceso a imágenes ASP (Not allowed to load local resource)

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy realizando un sitio, en el que tengo un modulo de donde pueden visualizar los registros capturados, y evidencias agregadas por cada registro, dentro de la captura no tengo ningún problema la web carga en dispositivos móviles, se toma la fotografía y se almacena en una ruta en el servidor y esa ruta en la DB, cuando visualizo los registros armo una tabla donde cargo todos los atributos del registro además de un Carousel (bootstrap), donde se deberían añadir las imágenes, cuando las añado, la consola de Chrome indica que el recurso no puede ser cargado, intente con el helper UrlHelper y VirtualPathData, pero sigue sin cargar el recurso:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  @foreach(var photos in Listascarpevidence)
   {
     <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src=@itemev.Evidencia class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
     </div>
    }
</div>
```

En la tabla de DB tengo registrado el recurso en el campo `Evidencia` de a siguiente manera:

```
D:\Evidence\21y06y202212m13m48pm2image.jpg
```

Y el error que arroja es este:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Evidence/21y06y202212m13m48pm2image.jpg
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque desde la pagina web no vas a tener permiso de entrar a una carpeta externa al ambiente(directorio) de la pagina web. lo que puedes hacer es guardarlo en la carpeta wwwroot o tambien podrias crear un controlador que vaya a la ruta y te traiga el archivo. pero se me hace más fácil y rápido que muevas la ruta

Por ejemplo yo aquí lo estoy guardando en **wwwroot/Adjuntos/Material** y al momento de traer la ruta solo usa:

> /Adjuntos/Material/abfe8dd8-6b19-4436-a6aa-2d8d9ca4b163.png

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya solo lo pones en el src de tu imagen

```
<image src="/Adjuntos/Material/abfe8dd8-6b19-4436-a6aa-2d8d9ca4b163.png"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si es realmente lo que termine haciendo, agregándola a la carpeta wwwroot, como dentro del equipo hay particiones, pregunta ¿Cómo buena practica siempre se recomienda poner contenido multimedia generado por los usuarios en este directorio  wwwroot?